# onClick event not working on Android Blank Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, onclick, onclicklistener, main-activity

I have a blank activity in Android Studio, and I have performed the following instructions but it is not working when I run the program.

1. Select the button and look for properties/attributes panel on the right.
2. Assign the name onClick to the android:onClick property of your Button.
3. Implement the following method in the Main_Activity file:

`public void onClick (View view) { 
    Toast.makeText(this, "Button 1 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}`

When I try to run this I get errors like:

- expecting a member declaration
- function declaration must have a name

Comment: These are the errors I keep getting and I feel like assignment left ALOT out. I am new to this, and I hope this question makes sense. 

"expecting a member declaration"
"function declaration must have a name"
etc...

Comment: @Williams, I need full code of main_activity file.

Comment: It is the same code that is on a blank activity. I am sorry I don't have it pulled up right now :( I will as soon as I get home but the main activity as I recall just has the generic class code. My professor has not been helpful in this so far and literally just gave those instructions only. But as soon as I get home I will add it here. Thank you

Comment: I found an image online that looks just like it. The first screenshot on this page: https://www.javaworld.com/article/3104621/mobile-java/android-studio-for-beginners-part-2-explore-and-code-the-app.html

Comment: but like I said I will get the exact code when I get home...

Comment: @williams, checked the url. you should add `implement View.SetOnClickListener `.

Comment: Ok I will try that out. Thank you so much!

Comment: good. keep in touch. thanks, @Williams. good friend.

Comment: I've Reworded into a more generic question.

Answer (score 0):

1)in Xml file of you Activity set onClick property of button with specified function name 
**android:onClick:"onClick"**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

2)after this put same function inside your activity but with parameter like this
**public void onClick (View view)**

```
public void onButtonClick(View view){
   Toast.makeText(this, "Button 1 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

3) when you click on button provided method gets called

Note: function name can be anything but access specifier, return type and parameter has to be same.

Comment: Thank you!! That fixed my problem!! You are awesome!!

Comment: it's my pleasure

Comment: @A.Williams, Just a reminder as you are a new user. You can always up vote and accept the answer if it helped and resolved your issue. :)

Comment: I did! Thanks :) It said it won't show but it is recorded. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Button yourButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.your_button_id)  
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Button 1 pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Please try this in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Using the XML attribute `android:onClick` to trigger a click event. Only need two steps:

1.assign `android:onClick` to button like this:

```
 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Click me!" 
    android:onClick="btnClicked" />
```

2 In activity define a function named btnClicked like this:

```
   public void btnClicked(View v) { 
            Log.d("MR.bool", "Button1 was clicked "); 
   }
```

Notice: don't mix this way with `setOnClickListener`,just only above two steps.